# How can I get grayscale value with PIL?

Tags: python

I did a code to print all of the images pixel's grayscale values

Here is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageColor
im = Image.open('upvote.png')
im = im.resize((50, 50))
im = im.convert('LA')#convert to grayscale
for i in range(50):
    print('\n')
    for j in range(50):
        pixel = im[i, j]# get pixel value
        print(pixel)
```

It is expected to get something like this:
1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
....
depending on the image

but I am getting this error:

```py
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, if anyone ever sees this here is how I solved it:
Instead of this:

```py
pixel = im[i, j]
```

I used this:

```
pixel = im.getpixel((i, j))
```